# Save file with custom delimiter Excel

Tags: excel

I would like to know if it is possible with Excel to save a file with a delimiter that I can choose?

Thank you

Comment: I don't thik it could be possible, but, if you save a CSV file, with a macro you can change the commas with any another character.

Comment: Does [this page](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21456/export-or-save-excel-files-with-pipe-or-other-delimiters-instead-of-commas/) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.
Go to your Region and Language settings in the Control Panel of Windows.
Click "Additional Settings" on tab "Format".
Change the List Separator to your own custom delimiter character.

Answer (score 0):

May be this could give some help:

```
Sub changeCharacter()
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim text As String
    Dim textline As String

    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename() 'open your TXT/CSV file

    Open myFile For Input As #1 'open just for input

    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline
        textline = Replace(textline, ",", "#")
        text = text & Chr(10) & textline
    Loop

        '#####################################3
        'EOF = End Of File
        ' and this function sends true when reach the last
        ' line of the file...
        '
        'Line Input #1, textline
        ' take the next line in the TXT/CSV file an store it inside
        ' "textline" to replace the character "," for "#" using:
        'textline = Replace(textline, ",", "#")
        ' and store the result again inside "textline"
        ' and finally, store the result into "text" to use it later
        '#####################################3

    Close #1 'close the TXT/CSV fiel

    Open myFile For Output As #1 'open the same file againg,
                                 'now to store the resulting data
                                 'inside the file
    Write #1, text 'write the data into the file
    Close #1 'close it againg, now with the changes...
End Sub
```

This is not to save the file with a different delimeter, but could help to change it.